# Center mediaelements.js video

Tags: css

Hi I have a mediaelements.js video which I want to centre horizontally in its container div, this used to work but I have changed it so that the video is responsive. I am also using Slick on the videoPlayerSlideWrap (it slides through many of the videoPlayerSlide divs, although only one of them is a video the rest are images and the images centre themselves perfectly) so I don't know if slick is interfering with mediaelements.js or something. Thank you in advance.

The players code:

```
<div class="videoPlayerSlideWrap" id="contentSlide">

<div class="videoPlayerSlide">

    <video width="100%" height="100%" style="width:100%; height:100%;" controls id="player1" preload="auto">
        <source type="video/youtube" src="<?php print $storyMediaURL; ?>"/>
    </video>

</div>

</div>
```

The CSS:

```
div.videoPlayerSlide {
    width:100%;
    min-width:580px;
    max-width:940px;
    height:529px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

div.videoPlayerSlideWrap.contentSlide {position:relative;}

div.videoPlayerSlideWrap {
    width:100%;
    height:529px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:0px;
    background:#000;
}
```

EDIT:

Live link of the issue: http://www.umoja.org.uk/fullArticle.php?s=52

Comment: It's good to provide an example in jsfiddle. As far as I know it works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/keryfw21/, made some changes to make it sure. What do you exactly want to center? The video inside the wrapper? Or the wrapper inside it's main container?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a jsfiddle account at the moment.

Comment: I want to centre the wrapper inside its main container, this works fine for the standard html5 video player but once mediaelements does its thing the player goes to the left of the main container.

Comment: Here is a live link of the problem http://www.umoja.org.uk/fullArticle.php?s=52

Comment: "Sorry, I don't have a jsfiddle account at the moment" - jsfiddle is free and doesn't require an account; you can use it anonymously. You can also use the built in stackoverflow snippets.

Comment: I did not know that. I have provided a live example of the problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a conflict between [slick.js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and your CSS rules. Add the following CSS rule to your `main.css`, this should correct the problem.

```
div.videoPlayerSlide.slick-slide {
   float:none;
}
```

Comment: I need max-width there though because it can't go wider than 940px, but at the same time the width:100% even though it isn't going to be 100% is needed to allow it to be responsive. Not sure how to get around this.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much, this has been bugging me all day.